# Google Sheets - Check if any string from column is in certain cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of strings, e.g.

`A1: A
A2: B
A2: C`

And I want a formula to check if any of those strings are in another cell, say B2. Is this possible with google sheets? `FIND` only seems to work on single strings and doesn't appear to accept a range of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings are in ColumnA (in separate cells), then perhaps:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2,textjoin("|",1,A1:A))
```

(Case sensitive.)